# How to run Anki-Qt script without requiring a breakpoint?

Tags: python, pyqt, event-handling, anki

If I run the toy script below as shown:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/anki')
import aqt

app = aqt._run(argv=['/usr/bin/anki', '--profile=test'], exec=False)
# breakpoint()
print(repr(aqt.mw.col))
aqt.mw.cleanupAndExit()
```

...I get the following output, which is not right:

```
$ python3 /tmp/ankiq.py
None
```

If I uncomment the commented statement, however, and re-run the modified script, I get the correct output (eventually):

```
$ python3 /tmp/ankiq.py
> /tmp/ankiq.py(8)<module>()
-> print(repr(aqt.mw.col))
(Pdb) c
<anki.collection._Collection object at 0x7f32ec1417b8>
```

I would like to avoid the need for the `breakpoint()` statement (and for having to hit `c` whenever I want to run such code).

My guess is that, when the `breakpoint()` statement is commented out, the `print` statement happens before `aqt.mw` has been fully initialized.

(I tried replacing the `breakpoint()` statement with `time.sleep(1)`, but when I run the script with this modification, it hangs before ever printing any output.)

**Q:** How can I modify the toy script above so that, by the time the `print` statement executes, `aqt.mw.col` has its correct value?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use the anki plugins *from* within anki?

Comment: @musicamante: I'm not working on/with an anki plugin.  I want to develop a cron (i.e. unsupervised/automatically running/non-interactive) script that accesses and possibly modifies my collection.anki2 database.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Apologies for rolling back your edit.  The Python package this question is about consists primarily of a PyQt app, and I think the problem I am having with this has to do with this fact.

Comment: @kjo Try calling `app.processEvents()` before the other statements.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Thank you very much!  When I added `app.processEvents()` before the `print` statement, I still got output `None`, but adding `while aqt.mw.col is None: app.processEvents()` did the trick!  I would be happy to accept this as the answer if you care to post it.

Comment: @kjo Glad you got it working. I have added an answer based on the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that calling `aqt._run(*args, exec=False)` returns a `QApplication` object - but without starting its event-loop. To manually process pending events, you could therefore try calling `app.processEvents()`.

---

From the comments, it appears the exact solution is as follows:

```
while aqt.mw.col is None: 
    app.processEvents()
```